# SQLs generated for Oracle from an application

Tags: sql, oracle, ip, erp

We have an ERP application installed on many desktop PCs. This ERP is connected to Oracle database. How can I know from which PC (IP address) which sql is generated. Is there anything we can configure in Oracle database to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Manager would give you this information. Otherwise you can query v$session / v$sql, something like:

```
select sq.sql_text
        , machine
        , type
from v$sql sq
        , v$session s
where sq.sql_id = s.sql_id
and type != 'BACKGROUND'
```

You can tweak this to filter on your specific SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks...how long the sqls are stored in v$sql

Comment: There are two columns in v$sql; sql_text is a VARCHAR2(1000) and so contains the first 1000 characters. SQL_FULL_TEXT is a CLOB which contains the full text.

Comment: Thanks again...I mean when the sqls are overwritten with the new sqls in v$sql. How many minutes a sql can stay in v$sql :)

Comment: it depends on the size of shared pool and rate of execution plan creation